# Bokeh server- Error running application handler

Tags: python, error-handling, server, bokeh, handler

Hello guys: I started to use Bokeh and used the example "crossfilter" applied for my own data.
It worked fine and I did see the interactive plot in my Jupiter notebook. However, when I tried to use the bokeh server, it showed an error message as follows at the command prompt: 
bokeh serve --show myplot.py
Error running application handler : name 'null
NameError: name 'null' is not defined.
(Sorry about that, it could be not a new question, I did search some internet answers but it did not work for me). Any comments are really helpful.

Here are my origin codes:

```
"""
An example demonstrating how to put together a cross-selector app based
on the FIFA dataset.
"""
hv.extension("bokeh","matplotlib")
import holoviews as hv
import panel as pn
import panel.widgets as pnw

from bokeh.sampledata.autompg import autompg

columns = sorted(df.columns)
discrete = [x for x in columns if df[x].dtype == object]
continuous = [x for x in columns if x not in discrete]
quantileable = [x for x in continuous if len(df[x].unique()) > 20]

x = pnw.Select(name='X-Axis', value='Overall Rating', options=quantileable)
y = pnw.Select(name='Y-Axis', value='Pace', options=quantileable)
size = pnw.Select(name='Size', value='None', options=['None'] + quantileable)
color = pnw.Select(name='Color', value='None', options=['None'] + quantileable)

@pn.depends(x.param.value, y.param.value, color.param.value, size.param.value) 
def create_figure(x, y, color, size):
    opts = dict(cmap='rainbow', width=800, height=600, padding=0.1, line_color='black')
    if color != 'None':
        opts['color'] = color 
    if size != 'None':
        opts['size'] = hv.dim(size).norm()*20
    return hv.Points(df, [x, y], label="%s vs %s" % (x.title(), y.title())).opts(**opts)

widgets = pn.WidgetBox(x, y, color, size, width=200)

pn.Row(widgets, create_figure).servable('Cross-selector')
```

---

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44729057/displaying-bokeh-crossfilter-example helps?  These examples seem to depend on a special bokeh server running.

Comment: Could you also comment on the versions of bokeh, panel and holoviews you are using?